# Finder- Reopen Last Closed Window

Tags: macos, finder, preferences

Finder does not seem to navigate to the last folder opened. For instance, when I am saving several files or images - it would be nice to (and used to ) open in the last place I placed something - now it defaults to "User" and I have to navigate each time - very frustrating.

Comment: You are correct that Finder doesn't work in the way you describe. Are you looking perhaps for software to add this function like [DefaultFolderX](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) or more interested in knowing if you have missed a setting?

Answer (score 14):

In Finder, use the `Go` in menu => `Recent Folders`. This is the closest you can get to

> "open[ing] in the last place I placed something"

[image]

**More Information**:

If you don't like the default, you can change the default Finder window to open as well. Go to `Preferences in Finder`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Do you happen to know of any hot keys that will perform that same task (the equiv. of `shift + cmd + t` in Chrome to open the last closed tab)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the OS Mojave, Finder problem

- Click on top-left Apple icon
- Then click on System Preferences
- Then General
- And then uncheck the box saying, "`Close windows when quitting an app`"
- It will save your session of Finder and when you restart your system it will show you last opened tabs of the session

> NOTE: before Shut Down or Restart of the system, don't close the
>   Finder

[image: Mojave Finder solution]